# [self addSubview:_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label]]; I don't understand

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am study a source code, and find the below code:

```
- (UILabel *)stateLabel
{
    if (!_stateLabel) {
        [self addSubview:_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label]]; // there I can not understand, how it execute?
    }
    return _stateLabel;
}
```

The line:

```
[self addSubview:_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label]];
```

I can not understand, how it execute? 
first execute the `[UILabel mj_label]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
[self addSubview:_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label]];
```

is equivalent to:

```
_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label];
[self addSubview:_stateLabel];
```

In C (and Objective-C), the result of an assignment expression is the same as the assigned value.

So when you do:

```
[self addSubview:_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label]];
```

imagine parentheses are there:

```
[self addSubview:(_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label])];
```

This sort of thing is bad form because imagine a simple typo in an `if` statement:

```
if (someInt = 5) {
}
```

when you actually meant:

```
if (someInt == 5) {
}
```

In the first, bad `if` statement, you first assign (instead of compare) the value 5 to `someInt`. And then the `if` looks at the result of `5` and treats that non-zero value as true. So no matter what the original value of `someInt` was, it will always become `5` and the `if` will always evaluate as true.

Answer (score 0):

It's poor form, but the statement relies on the fact that the value of the assignment statement `(a = b)` is `b`.  So, the clearer (and a little more verbose) way to state is:

```
// ...
_stateLabel = [UILabel mj_label];
[self addSubview:_stateLabel];
// ...
```